# scala - creating objects without making constructor parameter a member of the object

Tags: class, scala, object

I have

```
class Address(elem: scala.xml.Elem){
    val attr1 = (elem \ "attr1") text
    ...
}
```

I do not want elem to be a member of Address to keep the the footprint to minimum as I create few millions of such objects in memory. What is the scala way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You achieve it just the way you've shown.  Just make sure you only refer to `elem` as part of the class initializer, not in other methods where it will have to be stored so it can be recalled.

Here's the bytecode for what you wrote (use `javap -p ClassName` on compiled classes):

```
public Address(scala.xml.Elem);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #18; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   aload_1
   6:   ldc #19; //String attr1
   8:   invokevirtual   #25; //Method scala/xml/Elem.$bslash:(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/xml/NodeSeq;
   11:  invokevirtual   #30; //Method scala/xml/NodeSeq.text:()Ljava/lang/String;
   14:  putfield    #11; //Field attr1:Ljava/lang/String;
   17:  return
```

Note that there is only one `putfield`, namely the one to initialize the val `attr1`.  If `elem` were saved inside the class, it would need its own `putfield`.  If you change the `val` to a `def`, you get instead:

```
public Address(scala.xml.Elem);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield    #12; //Field elem:Lscala/xml/Elem;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   invokespecial   #31; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   9:   return
```

where you can see that the `Elem` has been stored so the `def` can use it on each invocation.

If you *want* the `Elem` to be stored and accessible, you would have to declare the class

```
class Address(val elem: scala.xml.Elem) { ... }
```

(note the `val`).

Only if you use a case class is the constructor argument is always stored: case classes are designed for pattern matching, and of course you need to store the argument if you're going to try to match against it later.